# siunitx table: column with and without units

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx

I have a table listing several properties. Some of them have a unit some don't. All have a uncertainty. Now I want to align them properly in the table using the siunitx package.
See following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
\sisetup{multi-part-units=single}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[b]{|l|S|}
   \hline
    Property    & {Value} \\\hline
    A           & \SI{284.98 \pm 5.2}{\meter} \\\hline
    B           & \SI{3.86 \pm 0.3}{\kilo\gram} \\\hline
    C           & \num{96.4 \pm 42.3} \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The problem is, that none of the values are aligned correctly.

**Update:**
The result should like the following:

```
A    284.98 +/-  5.2 m
B      3.86 +/-  0.3 kg
C     96.4  +/- 42.3
```

However, the alignment of the uncertainty is not necessarily required.

Comment: What's the desired alignment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
\sisetup{multi-part-units=single}

\begin{document}    
   \begin{tabular}{
l
S[table-format=3.2]@{\,\( \pm \)\,}
S[table-format=2.1]@{\,}
s[table-unit-alignment = left]
}
\toprule
Property    &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Value}  \\
\midrule
A           & 284.98 & 5.2 & \si{\meter} \\
B           & 3.86 & 0.3 & \si{\kilo\gram}  \\
C           & 96.4 & 42.3  \\
\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

In this MWE, I have separated the number and the uncertainty into two columns that are automatically separated by the +- sign. With `table-format=3.2` I can make sure, that the numbers are aligned correctly with respect to the decimal separator. The units are in a third column and left-aligned. Additionally, I have removed all vertical lines and have replaced `\hrule`s by the lines of the `booktabs` package.

[image]

Comment: You could keep the uncertainties in the same column as the values and use `separate-uncertainty`

Comment: @JosephWright I tried this as well, but was unfortunately not able to set up the `table-format` of this column option correctly.

Answer (score 5):

I came across this post as I was looking for the same question (but noch using the plus-minus sign in between the columns). As the current answer does not work anymore, I decided to add a new answer for future reference.

As of **v3.0.0** of siunitx (see the [Changelog](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#v300)) the option `table-unit-alignment` and, I guess, with it the `s` column type were removed.

The new option is probably `S[table-text-alignment = left]`. At least it works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
\sisetup{multi-part-units=single}

\begin{document}    
   \begin{tabular}{
l
S[table-format=3.2]@{\,\( \pm \)\,}
S[table-format=2.1]@{\,}
S[table-text-alignment = left]
}
\toprule
Property    &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Value}  \\
\midrule
A           & 284.98 & 5.2 & \si{\meter} \\
B           & 3.86 & 0.3 & \si{\kilo\gram}  \\
C           & 96.4 & 42.3  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!